# Processing, validating, and sanitizing data

Tags: php, forms, validation

Ok I have been stuck on this for some time now. I have a form. The form is in "index.php".
I send the form data to a php file called, "processuserform". I extract all the inputs and assigned them each to their own variable. I then took each variable and ran them through a function that I believe trims and strips the input from any unwanted characters. Within the same function I transformed any special characters into their HTML forms. Next I tried to validate the email. I used a PHP filter for this. I am uncertain on many things and have been searching for quite some time for an answer or at least a path to follow so I can learn how to properly sanitize and validate information. I am under the impression I will need to treat passwords different then everything else and will learn that after I learn how to validate and sanitize information. What you see below is what I have gathered from various sources on the net, which may end up being an incorrect way of designing a web page. I have achieved client side validation using Javascript but am fearful for my site because I do not have server side validation up. What happens if someone, who has javascript turned off, enters the wrong kind of information? How do they get sent back to the registration part and told they have made a mistake. I dont want people being led to a blank screen when they incorrectly enter information. I just want my site to be validated on the server side. I have literally been trying to learn this for 3 months. It is not that I am unintelligent but cannot find a set way to go about doing this. With so many ways I am confused ast to the path to take and what to do next. I will leave my code below and hopefully you guys will have compassion and patience for me. Thanks in advance.

```
 ==========================================================================
  Form
 ==========================================================================
 <form method="POST" name="signup" action="php/processuserform.php">

 <input id="firstname" onkeyup="validateFirstName()"  placeholder="First Name" 
 type="text" /><label id="firstnameprompt"></label>

 <br><br>

 <input id="lastname" onkeyup="validateLastName()"  placeholder="Last Name" 
 type="text"/>
 <label id="lastnameprompt"></label>

 <br><br>


 <input id="Email" onkeyup="validateEmail()"  placeholder="Email" type="text" /><label 
 id="Emailprompt"></label>

 <br /><br />

 <input id="Password" onkeyup="validatePassword()"  placeholder="Create Password" 
 type="password" /><label id="Passwordprompt"></label>

 <br /><br />


 <strong>Male</strong><input id="Gender" type="radio" name="sex" value="male">
 <strong>Female</strong><input id="Gender" type="radio" name="sex" value="female">

 <br /><br />

 Click "Submit" if you agree to <a href="#">"Terms And Conditions"</a>
 <br>
 <input id="submit" onclick="return validateUserRegistration()" value="Submit" 
 type="submit" name="submit"/><label id="submitprompt"></label>

 <br /><br />
 <hr>
 </form> 





 ====================================================================
  //How I am Processing it.
 ====================================================================


 <?php

 //====================================
 //Variables

 $first_name= check_input($_POST['firstname']);
 $last_name= check_input($_POST['lastname']);
 $email= check_input($_POST['Email']);
 $password= check_input($_POST['Password']);
 $gender= check_input($_POST['Gender');

 //====================================
 //Trim and strip first name

 function check_input($first_name)
 { 
 $first_name = trim($first_name);
 $first_name = stripslashes($first_name);
 $first_name = htmlspecialchars($first_name);
 return $first_name; }; 

 //====================================
 //Trim and strip last name

 function check_input($last_name)
 { 
 $last_name = trim($last_name);
 $last_name = stripslashes($last_name);
 $last_name = htmlspecialchars($last_name);
 return $last_name; }; 

 //====================================
 //Trim and strip email

 function check_input($email)
 { 
 $email = trim($email);
 $email = stripslashes($email);
 $email = htmlspecialchars($email);
 return $email; }; 

 //=====================================
 //Trim and Strip Password

 function check_input($password)
 { 
 $password = trim($password);
 $password = stripslashes($password);
 $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
 return $password; }; 
 //======================================
 //Trim and strip Gender
 function check_input($gender)
 { 
 $gender = trim($gender);
 $gender = stripslashes($gender);
 $gender = htmlspecialchars($gender);
 return $gender; }; 

 //=========================================================
 //Validate Email

 $email

 if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
 {
 echo 'This should be a valid email';
 }
 else
 {
 echo 'You need some guidance':
 }


 //========================================================


  $hostname="this is right";
  $username="this is right";
  $password="this is right";
  $dbname="this is right";

   $db_conx = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to
  connect to database! Please try again later.");

  if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
  }

  $select = mysqli_select_db($db_conx,$dbname);

  mysqli_query($db_conx,"INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password, 
  gender)
  VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$password', '$gender')");
  mysqli_close($db_conx);

  header("Location: pages/profile.php")
  ?>
```

Comment: You should learn PHP - its pretty easy to sanitize data inputs for database handling, PDO does it for you for example. Once you have learnt the basics of PHP we can help you until then SO can't help that much you need some basic understanding of the language, try a book ?

Comment: So you're trying to ask if there's a better way of sanitizing and validating inputted data? I feel like I read a rant.

Comment: @charlesisjan I did rant a bit, but what I was simply wanting is for someone to give me an example, using one of my inputs, on how to properly sanitize and validate input data. If I could be given an example then I would be able to see how it was done and then be able to complete the rest by myself. Simply put I would like it if someone could sanitize and validate one of my inputs, like firstname, so I can see how it is properly done. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after you removed the unwanted characters from all of your user inputted variables, you now have to validate them as well!

From what I have learned in the past, one of the assumptions you should have as a developer is to NEVER trust that all users know the correct inputs for forms! Never trust the user! So with that in mind, we go and validate server side.

Validation in simplest terms is just making sure that the user inputs data that will work (I don't know the right way to put it) in a way to maintain the quality of your application.

Let's take one of your variables for example.

```
$email
```

Okay, you did a validation to check if it's an email, but there are better ways to validate it and you also need to check for other factors such as if the user inputs a blank space etc.

```
function validateEmail($email) 
    {
    //Regex is a great way to validate email. This checks if it has one @ sign and also the lengths of the email.
        if (!preg_match("/^[^@]{1,64}@[^@]{1,255}$/", $email)) 
            {
        // Email invalid because wrong number of characters in one section, or wrong number of @ symbols.
                return false;
            }
//check if the input was something other than a whitespace.
//Even if you put inside the textfield "required" in html, a whitespace will still be a   //valid input so you better check to make sure that users aren't allowed to enter empty //fields!
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$email))
            {
                return false;
            }
        return true;
    }
```

This is just an example of how you can validate email using Regular Expressions.

You can even validate whether or not the domain is a real domain, or you can validate if the email contains any profane words and such. The key is to know what you don't WANT going into your system.

Make sure you also sanitize your queries in order to avoid any attacks.

Hope this sort of helps!

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much. I was wanting an example and you gave me one. I cannot tell you how grateful I am. If I could give you a point I would, but my reputation does not permit me to do so. It definitely did help. Thanks once more.

Comment: I was able to get the reputation points to give you your well deserved point.